# How to distinguish a function locally summable.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I would like to understand if there is a way to tell if a function $f\in L_{loc}(a,b)$, with $(a,b)$ finite or infinite. I know the definition but when I look at a function I do not know what tests to use to define whether it is locally summable.

For example the following function;

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{3}e^{i\pi x}}{x^2+4}$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this might be too broad.  Could you give some specific examples?

Comment: I added an example to the question thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hint: this function is continuous.  What do you know about continuous functions on compact sets?

Comment: They are automatically locally summable?I'm sorry, in theory are not very prepared because I do not have the need for my purposes

Comment: Forget all about summability for a moment.  What is one of the very first things you learned about continuous functions and compact sets?

Comment: they not diverge are limited

Comment: Yes, they are bounded.  Now if you have a closed interval $[c,d]$, and a function $f$ which is bounded on $[c,d]$, say $|f|\le M$ on $[c,d]$, what can you say about $\int_{[c,d]} |f|$?

Comment: Can be integrated according to Riemann definition?